# openFullscreen() throwing error, when called for the second time

Tags: angular

**tt.component.html**

```
 <a class="fancy-button"><span (click)="onselect()"><i size="2x"
            class="fa fa-ticket"></i>Start</span></a>
```

**tt.component.ts**

```
 export class ttComponent implements OnInit {
  elem;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = document.documentElement;
   })
     onselect() {
            this.router.navigate(['test']);
            this.openFullscreen();
          }    

         openFullscreen() {
                if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
                  this.elem.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                  /* Firefox */
                  this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                  /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
                  this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                  /* IE/Edge */
                  this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
                }
              }
     }
```

**Above code opens the test.html in fullscreen, but when the user presses ESC button, it is minimized. So I used another button in test screen to call openFullscreen(). But I'm getting an error**

**test.component.html**

```
 <a class="fancy-button"><span (click)="openFullscreen()"><i size="2x" class="fa fa-ticket"></i>Fullscreen</span></a>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
openFullscreen() {
        if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
          this.elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          /* Firefox */
          this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
          this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          /* IE/Edge */
          this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
      }

    fullscreenmode(){

    if(this.toggleClass == 'ft-minimize'){
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-maximize';
      console.log("Switch to full screen")
      this.openFullscreen();
    }
    else{
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-minimize';
    }
```

}

[image]

**Please help me in solving it. Thanks in advance**

Comment: We need more info. How `this.elem` get a reference to what you want? How is the component minimized (is it a dialog that is hidden or is it removed from the DOM with an `*ngIf`?

Comment: By minimized, I mean the component displays in normal mode. When the user presses ESC key, the screen comes to the normal mode. But I want the user to go back to full-screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

That error is in your code (unrelated to this plugin), you are trying to call functions inside the head tag, those are called before the entire document is loaded, so the element you are trying to use doesn't exist yet.
You need to either call them at the bottom of the body tag, where the other scripts are, or use a Ready function (like the one in jquery) or window.onload, as those will run the code after everything is loaded.

Please refer : [Git](https://github.com/ctd1500/videojs-hotkeys/issues/3) and [Morzila doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) for more details.

Or assign value to `this.elem` in `afterViewInit()`

Comment: Yeah, I've assigned value to this.elem. I've updated the code @Kapil Thakkar

Comment: Assign value in "afterViewInIt" instead of "ngInIt"